# find f(2) given the function defined by $ \int _0^{x^2} f(t)= x^2(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(t)$ is continuous and satisfies the condition for x>=0
$$ \int _0^{x^2} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t= x^2(x+1)$$

how do I find f(2) plug the 2 in the right side, or do so multiplying by $x^2$ derivative?

Comment: I added the variable of integration to the integral. Check it to make sure I am understanding what you are asking.

Comment: It is correct, my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Differentiating both sides you get
$$f(x^2) 2x=2x(x+1)+x^2$$

Plug in $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So if have another f(x) in the integration limit i shall find the derivative and plug an x that makes f(x)=f(2)?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate:
$$F(x^2)-F(0)=x^3+x^2$$
Change:
$$x^2=t \Rightarrow x^3=t^{3/2}$$
Get: 
$$F(t)-F(0)=t^{3/2}+t$$
Differentiate:
$$f(t)=\frac{3}{2}t^{1/2}+1$$
Plug $t=2:$

$$f(2)=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

By $t=u^2$,

$$2\int_a^xf (u^2)udu=\int_a^x (3u^2+2u) du$$

$$2 (x-a)f (c^2)c=(x-a)(3d^2+2d) $$

with $a\le c,d\le x $.
take $a=\sqrt {2} $ and make $x\to a $.